# Fortran array unclassiable statement

Tags: fortran, gfortran

```
  program rk4
  real x(200), y(200), h, k1, k2, k3, k4
  integer i
  read*,x(0),y(0),h
  do i=0,10
  k1=x(i)-y(i)+2
  x(i+1)=x(i)+h
  k2=(x(i)+h/2)-(y(i)+(h/2)*k1))+2
  k3=(x(i)+h/2)-(y(i)+(h/2)*k2))+2
  k4=(x(i+1))-(y(i)+h*(k3))+2
  y(i+1)=y(i)+(h/6)*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)
  print*, 'x=', x(i+1), 'y=', y(i+1)
  enddo
  end
```

At line 9 and 10:

```
  k2=(x(i)+h/2)-(y(i)+(h/2)*k1))+2
  k3=(x(i)+h/2)-(y(i)+(h/2)*k2))+2
```

I'm getting "Unclassifiable statement at (1)", with (1) pointing to k2 and k3. I can't see what I'm doing wrong as k1 and k4 follows a similar structure and it seems like there isn't anything wrong with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the error message comes from too many right parentheses ")" for `k2` and `k3`. Another error is that arrays `x` and `y` need to be declared as `x(0:200)` and `y(0:200)`, because you are accessing `x(0)` and `y(0)`. If the above two points are fixed, the code should work correctly.

As side notes, I really recommend to put `implicit none`, which is useful to detect potential bugs, and use floating-point literals such as 2.0 rather than 2 in floating point arithmetic (except for powers like `x**2`). In the code below, I have compared the analytical [solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Dsolve%5B%20y%27%5Bx%5D%20%3D%3D%20x%20-%20y%5Bx%5D%20%2B%202%2C%20y%5Bx%5D%2C%20x%20%5D) with your RK4 result, which seem to agree well with each other.

```
program rk4
implicit none                                   !<--- this is useful
real x(0:200), y(0:200), h, k1, k2, k3, k4      !<--- indices now start from 0
integer i
read *, x(0), y(0), h

do i = 0, 10
    x(i+1) = x(i) + h
    k1 = x(i) - y(i) + 2.0                                  ! y' = x - y + 2
    k2 = ( x(i) + h/2.0 ) - ( y(i) + h/2.0 * k1 ) + 2.0     !<--- ")" has been removed
    k3 = ( x(i) + h/2.0 ) - ( y(i) + h/2.0 * k2 ) + 2.0     !<--- here also
    k4 = ( x(i+1)       ) - ( y(i) + h     * k3 ) + 2.0
    y(i+1) = y(i) + h/6.0 * ( k1 + 2.0*k2 + 2.0*k3 + k4 )
    print*, 'x=', x(i+1), 'y(rk4)=', y(i+1), &
            'y(ana)=', x(i+1)+1.0 + (y(0)-x(0)-1.0) * exp(-x(i+1)+x(0))
enddo
end
```